# React: how to reference an external function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have onClick events in my html that calls a function to get the alt value of each list item (so getting the movie name). I want the next step to simply get the single value that the function got and insert it into a separate webpage. How would I go about doing it? I gave it a try but I'm still very new to react, so I'm aware this doesn't work.

My html:

```
<div class="now-showing">
   <ul class="movie-items">
      <li>
         <img src="/images/movie-a.jpg" alt="Movie A">
         <button><a href="/html/bookticket.html" onClick="getMovieName(event)">BOOK</a></button>
      </li>
      <li>
         <img src="/images/movie-b.jpg" alt="Movie B">
         <button><a href="/html/bookticket.html" onClick="getMovieName(event)">BOOK</a></button>                      
      </li>
      <li>
         <img src="/images/movie-c.jpg" alt="Movie C">
         <button><a href="/html/bookticket.html" onClick="getMovieName(event)">BOOK</a></button>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
 // getting movie name for movie bookings

let filmTitle = [];

function getMovieName(e) {
    let link = e.target;
    let img = link.closest("li").querySelector("img");
    let item = img.alt;
    filmTitle.push(item);
};

     // input movie title to schedule page

function AddTitle() {

    return (
        <div className="schedule-heading">
            <h2>Step 1: Select screening for {filmTitle}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddTitle />, document.querySelector('.screenings'));
```

So far on my second webpage, I'm only getting "Step 1: Select screening for". What changes or additions would I need to make?

Comment: sparate webpage? if so u will need server to store that image alt name.  or use cookie.
but if u want pure react u dont need reload whole page

Answer (score 0):

there what's wrong with your code:

**first:** u can't make img alt that saved by function exist when page reloading. so use ReactRouter instead if u wants to move to another page without reloading.
and make everything in pure react.
otherwise the img alt need to be stored in cookie or your server side.

**second:** react won't rerender without calling useState hook. so for react filmTitle will always blank. or u can also store it in another library for managing react state data like [redux](https://redux.js.org) or [mobx](https://mobx.js.org).

**note this code snippet doesnt run properly because stackoverflow blocked it.
so u need to run it in your own project.**

```js
const {
  BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Outlet,Link,useNavigate} = ReactRouterDOM
  
function MyMovie(props){
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const [data,setData] = React.useState([
  {imgsrc:"/images/movie-a.jpg",imgalt:"Movie A",href:"/bookticket"},
  {imgsrc:"/images/movie-b.jpg",imgalt:"Movie B",href:"/bookticket"},
  {imgsrc:"/images/movie-c.jpg",imgalt:"Movie C",href:"/bookticket"}])
  const bookMovie=(v)=>{
    props.setFilmTitle(v.imgalt)
    navigate(v.href)
  }
  return <div className="now-showing">
   <ul className="movie-items">
    {data.map(v=>
      <li key={v.imgalt}>
         <img src={v.imgsrc} alt={v.imgalt}/>
         <button onClick={()=>bookMovie(v)}>BOOK</button>
      </li>)}
      
   </ul>
</div>
}

// input movie title to schedule page

function AddTitle(props) {
  return ( <div className = "schedule-heading" >
    <h2 > Step 1: Select screening for {props.filmTitle} < /h2> 
    </div>
  )
}

function Page(){
  return <div>
    Welcome!
    <Outlet/>
    </div>
}

function App(){
  const [filmTitle,setFilmTitle] = React.useState([])
  return <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Page />}>
        <Route index element={ <MyMovie filmTitle={filmTitle} setFilmTitle={setFilmTitle}/>} />
        <Route path="bookticket" element={ <AddTitle filmTitle={filmTitle}/>}/>
       </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
 
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.querySelector('.screenings'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/history@5/umd/history.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@6/umd/react-router.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6/umd/react-router-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div class="screenings">

</div>
```